# Django home page inactive when admin active

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-admin

First of all, i'm a newbie. I'm running Django 1.4.3 on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. I'm going through the tutorials on the Django site and i'm noticing that my homepage doesn't work when my admin is active.

I have uncommented the admin lines in urls.py and the admin page works fine, but the the home page wont load:

**Using the URLcong defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patters, in this order:
   1. ^admin/
 the current URL, , didnt match any of these.**

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^admin/doc/' include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/' include(admin.site.urls)
)
```

admin.py:

```
from polls.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Poll)
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: You haven't shown your urls.py, so it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Please show your `urls.py`

Comment: sorry! i added in urls.py and admin.py

Comment: you haven't added any urls for your app, re-read the tutorial, it tells you exactly howto embed app urls in your main url config.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls) of the Tutorial, you need to add additial entries to your `urls.py`.  It's unclear how you had a homepage view without any entries (besides for the admin), if you were running the development server with `./manage.py runserver`.

If you have a a viewable homepage at `http://localhost:8000/` with an entry in your `urlpatterns` like:

```
url(r'^$', 'polls.views.index'),
```

as long as `polls` was on the python path, had a `views.py` in it which contained a callable named `index`.